# keyPathsForValuesAffecting<Key> for NSUserDefaults

Tags: cocoa, nsuserdefaults, key-value-observing

I'd like to have a variable in my interface update automatically as other values change.

I've used keyPathsForValuesAffecting which works perfectly fine for all the same variables in the same class. I can't get is to work if the variable is stored in the NSUserDefaults. I tried this:

```
- (id) init
{
  myDefaultsController = [NSUserDefaultsController sharedUserDefaultsController];
}

+ (NSSet *)keyPathsForValuesAffectingSumXYZ
{
  return [NSSet setWithObjects: @"x", @"y", @"myDefaultsController.values.z", nil];
}
```

sumXYZ is a readonly variable.

What should I do to get this to work?

Thanks a lot for your help.